# MySQL IF statement on a calculated column

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use a calculated column in an SQL statement that uses an 'IF'Statement in the 'Where' clause.

My query is down below. I keep getting the error

`Unknown column 'e_owner_id_church' in 'where clause'`

```
SELECT idu,fname,lname,id_file,friendly_name,file_name,uploaded_by,date_uploaded,
file_last_modified,owner_id, 
CASE WHEN owned_by='church' THEN church_name WHEN owned_by='user' THEN CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) END AS e_owner_name, 
CASE WHEN owned_by='church' THEN id_church END AS e_owner_id_church,
CASE WHEN owned_by='user' THEN idu END AS e_owner_id_user 
FROM files,file_affiliations,churches,users 
WHERE owner_id=IF(e_owner_id_church != null, e_owner_id_church, e_owner_id_user) 
GROUP BY file_id
```

Comment: SQL != programming language. use case when then

Comment: Does MySQL support COALESCE? WHERE owner_id = COALESCE(e_owner_id_church, e_owner_id_user)

Comment: yes, coalesce and instead of WHERE use HAVING because then you can use the aliases ;)

Comment: Or use a select in from list to create a derived table.

Comment: ...where are your `JOIN`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work as a workaround using `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT idu
     , fname
     , lname
     , id_file
     , friendly_name
     , file_name
     , uploaded_by
     , date_uploaded
     , file_last_modified
     , owner_id
     , CASE owned_by
        WHEN 'church' THEN church_name
        WHEN 'user' THEN CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname)
       END AS e_owner_name
     , CASE owned_by
        WHEN 'church' THEN id_church
        ELSE NULL
       END AS e_owner_id_church
     , CASE owned_by
        WHEN 'user' THEN idu
        ELSE NULL
       END AS e_owner_id_user
FROM files
   , file_affiliations
   , churches
   , users 
GROUP BY file_id
HAVING owner_id = IFNULL(e_owner_id_church, e_owner_id_user)
```

I'd like to warn you that this query is **not** standard SQL, in fact it selects fields which are neither included in the `GROUP BY` clause nor are the result of a group function.

Lastly, I think that the above could be simplified like this:

```
SELECT idu
     , fname
     , lname
     , id_file
     , friendly_name
     , file_name
     , uploaded_by
     , date_uploaded
     , file_last_modified
     , owner_id
     , CASE owned_by
        WHEN 'church' THEN church_name
        WHEN 'user' THEN CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname)
        ELSE NULL
       END AS e_owner_name
     , CASE owned_by
        WHEN 'church' THEN id_church
        WHEN 'user' THEN idu
       END AS e_owner_id
FROM files
   , file_affiliations
   , churches
   , users 
GROUP BY file_id
HAVING owner_id = e_owner_id
```

Comment: I got to rewrite the query using your answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

didnt try it but something like that should work:

```
SELECT idu,fname,lname,id_file,friendly_name,file_name,uploaded_by,date_uploaded,
file_last_modified,owner_id, 
CASE WHEN owned_by='church' THEN church_name WHEN owned_by='user' THEN CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) END AS e_owner_name, 
CASE WHEN owned_by='church' THEN id_church END AS e_owner_id_church,
CASE WHEN owned_by='user' THEN idu END AS e_owner_id_user 
FROM files,file_affiliations,churches,users 

GROUP BY file_id
HAVING owner_id = COALESCE(e_owner_id_church, e_owner_id_church, e_owner_id_user)
```